# After Spring Boot 2 upgade authorization server returns "At least one redirect_uri must be registered with the client."

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I upgraded our authorization server from Spring Boot 1.5.13.RELEASE to 2.1.3.RELEASE, and now I can authenticate, but I can no longer access the site. Here is the resulting URL and error after the POST to /login.

```
https://auth-service-test-examle.cfapps.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=proxy-service&redirect_uri=http://test.example.com/login&response_type=code&state=QihbF4

   OAuth Error

   error="invalid_request", error_description="At least one redirect_uri must be registered with the client."
```

To troubleshoot, I started a fresh project based on the Spring Security 5.1.4.RELEASE sample "oauth2authorizationserver." I layered on the features used in our Spring Boot 1.5.13 authorization server making sure the unit tests passed (except one test class). If I @Ignore the failing tests and deploy the code I get the problem described above.

The problem is reproducible in the AuthenticationTests.loginSucceeds() JUnit test that passed before the upgrade. It expects a 302, but now it gets a 403 because it goes to the root of the authentication server. I published the entire example on GitHub
[spring-security-5-upgrade_sso-auth-server](https://github.com/smitchell/spring-security-5-upgrade_sso-auth-server)

Clone the project and run the unit tests and you will see the failures.

Here are some of the key settings that can be found in the project on GitHub.

```
  public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private final String privateKey;

  private final String publicKey;

  private final AuthClientDetailsService authClientDetailsService;

  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  private final AuthUserDetailsService authUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  public AuthServerConfig(
      @Value("${keyPair.privateKey}") final String privateKey,
      @Value("${keyPair.publicKey}") final String publicKey,
      final AuthClientDetailsService authClientDetailsService,
      final AuthUserDetailsService authUserDetailsService,
      final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    this.privateKey = privateKey;
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
    this.authClientDetailsService = authClientDetailsService;
    this.authUserDetailsService = authUserDetailsService;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.withClientDetails(authClientDetailsService);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
        .userDetailsService(authUserDetailsService)
        .tokenStore(tokenStore());

  }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }


  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
  }

}

public class GlobalAuthenticationConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

  private final AuthUserDetailsService authUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  public GlobalAuthenticationConfig(final AuthUserDetailsService authUserDetailsService) {
    this.authUserDetailsService = authUserDetailsService;
  }

  @Override
  public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(authUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
  }
}

  @Configuration
  @Order(-20)
  protected class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      // @formatter:off
      http
          .requestMatchers().antMatchers(LOGIN, "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
         .formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN).permitAll();
      // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
  }

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final AuthUserDetailsService authUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  public WebSecurityConfig(AuthUserDetailsService authUserDetailsService) {
    this.authUserDetailsService = authUserDetailsService;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(authUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
  }

}
```

What else needs to be done in Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE to redirect the user back to the original webpage?

Comment: Steve, when I run that test using your sample, the HTML template doesn't get populated, e.g. the hidden input field still says `name="${_csrf.parameterName}"`, for example. This means that the csrf token doesn't get extracted. After manually bypassing that, I get a Spring Session exception. Actually, I also had to remove the `com.medzero` test dependency from the pom as well as a few test classes in the `domain` directory. Am I doing something wrong with your sample to reproduce the error you are trying to fix?

Comment: As for "how to register" with a `ClientDetailsService`, the registered uri should come back as part of your query to your `consumerRepository`. Note that it returns a `Consumer`, which extends `ClientDetails`. Note sure if you've already poked in that area, though.

Comment: @jzheaux The csrf template variables are populated when I run that same test on 1.5.13.RELEASE, so either I have an issue with my ThymeLeaf set-up, or I need to configure csrf on 2.1.3.RELEASE. I'll see what I find. Thank you!

Comment: Steve, were you able to make any progress on getting the GitHub project into a state that reproduces your issue? I'm happy to take another look. I believe I can also help you get passed the password encoder issue that you detail in the readme.

Comment: I went ahead and added a PR to your repo that fixes the loginSucceeds task. I didn't change anything relative to the two problems you mentioned, making me wonder how it is related. Can you help me understand the connection? https://github.com/smitchell/spring-security-5-upgrade_sso-auth-server/pull/1

Comment: @jzheaux Thanks for your help. The individual items may not be connected. The Spring Boot 1.5.13 to 2.1.3 upgrade broke Login. The GitHub project started as a copy of the oauth2authorizationservice sample in Spring Security 5.1.4. Release. I overlaid it with all of our code and tests. Everything worked except the CORS variable on the Login form is missing, and the oauthToken() test fails. My goal is a suite of security tests to confirm that the upgrade works. If I can get these tests working, then that should fix our production project too. If not, I need better tests.

Comment: @jzheaux I could write better login tests if I understood how our Spring Boot 1.5.13 login works today. A user goes to one of our sites. The browser is redirected to auth server /login page. The user POSTs to /login, and then gets redirected to the original URL. I assume the successful login redirect comes from the REFERRER header? None of our client (consumer) records has a redirect URL in the database, yet somehow the redirect is right. The test to verify our 2.1.3 login bug is fixed needs to verify the right redirect happens, but to write it I need to understand how it should work.

Comment: *** FIXED *** Josh (@jzheaux), the cors test in the project passes now: https://github.com/smitchell/spring-security-5-upgrade_sso-auth-server. When I renamed login.ftl to login.html some of the markup was invalid. Next, I will sync my production codebase to this example and go back to regression testing Spring Security 5 /login. If I still have that successful login redirect problem I will address that on a separate thread. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Also, the CORS issue is fixed and all the unit tests pass, but the successful login redirect is still broken when I deploy the code. ---> error="invalid_request", error_description="At least one redirect_uri must be registered with the client."

Comment: I submitted another PR to your repo regarding the redirecting test.

Answer (score 2):

It's important that OAuth 2.0 clients register a `redirect_uri` with Authorization Servers as [an Open Redirector mitigation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.1.5). As such, Spring Boot 2.1.x [has this as its default behavior](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1331), which is why you're seeing the error.

You can do one of two things:

## Add `redirect_uri`s, one for each client

Ideally, you'd update your clients to each have a registered `redirect_uri`, which would likely be retrieved in an implementation of `ClientDetailsService`:

```
public class MyClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {
    private final MyRespository myRepository;

    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) {
        return new MyClientDetails(this.myRepository.getMyDomainObject(clientId));
    }

    private static class MyClientDetails extends MyDomainObject implements ClientDetails {
        private final MyDomainObject mine;

        public MyClientDetails(MyDomainObject delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        // implement ClientDetails methods, delegating to your domain object

        public Set<String> getRegisteredRedirectUri() {
            return this.delegate.getRedirectUris();
        }
    }
}
```

This setup with the private subclass - while not necessary - is nice because it doesn't tie the domain object directly to Spring Security.

## Add a custom `RedirectResolver`

Or, you can customize the `RedirectResolver`, though this wouldn't secure against Open Redirects, which was the original reason for the change.

```
public MyRedirectResolver implements RedirectResolver {
    private final RedirectResolver delegate = new DefaultRedirectResolver();

    public String resolveRedirect(String redirectUri, ClientDetails clientDetails) {
        try {
            return this.delegate.resolveRedirect(redirectUri, clientDetails);
        } catch ( InvalidRequestException ire ) {
            // do custom resolution
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to add my own `RedirectResolver` but, I seem to have some issue registering it. I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException`. So, do we annotate the `MyRedirectResolver`? Also, we add it as `redirectResolver(customRedirectResolver())` to the `configure` method of `AuthorisationServierConfiugration? 

Could you maybe point me to an example repo or post where this has happened? or a gist?

@jzheaux

Comment: I figured it out, I had some classpath issues.